# Baffled with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{e^x-e^{\sin x} \over x-\sin x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> Calculate $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{e^x-e^{\sin x} \over x-\sin x}$$

**Personal work:**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{e^x-e^{\sin x} \over x-\sin x}=^{0 \over 0}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{e^x-e^{\sin x}\cdot\cos x \over 1-\cos x}=^{0 \over 0}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{{e^x-(e^{\sin x}\cdot\cos x-\sin x}\cdot e^{\sin x}\over \sin x})=\cdots$$

This gets to nowhere. Also, I substituted $t=e^{\sin x}$ but I could not replace the $e^x$.

Comment: You know, if you do L'Hospital just one more time it'll work.

Comment: This screams Taylor expansion

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph We are not taught taylor expansions.

Comment: dublicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851380/limit-lim-limits-x-to0-fracex-e-sin-xx-sin-x/1851399#1851399

Comment: It is useful to notice $e^x-e^{sin x}=(e^{x-\sin x}-1)e^{\sin x}$.

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that by standard limit for $t\to 0 \quad \frac{e^t-1}{t}\to 1$ since $(x-\sin x)\to 0\,$, we have

$${e^x-e^{\sin x} \over x-\sin x}=e^{\sin x}{e^{x-\sin x}-1 \over x-\sin x}\to 1\cdot 1=1$$

Comment: (+1) This is the most efficient approach given the "standard limit" that was referenced.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks a lot Mark, I really appreciate your kind comment! Often the importance of the standard limits is highly underestimated.

Comment: Just curious as to how you suggest one prove that "standard limit."  It can actually be shown directly from the limit definition of the exponential function.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes of course that's fine or as an alternative, without an knowledge about derivative by $e^x-1=y\implies \frac{e^x-1}{x}=\frac{y}{log(1+y)}\to 1$ and $\frac{log(1+x)}{x}\to 1$ can be deived by the definition of $e$.

Answer (score 4):

The mean value theorem says

$\dfrac {e^x-e^{y}}{x-y}=e^c$

Since $c→0$, we get limit is $1$.

Comment: It is true that $g$ is both continuous and differentiable at $\mathbb R$ therefore, in $[x,y]$. The mean value theorem says: $$f'(c)={f(b)-f(a) \over b-a}$$ and not $f'(x)^c$

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis $f(x)=e^x\Rightarrow f'(c)=\ldots$

Comment: IMO the best answer. Takes virtually no effort.

Answer (score 2):

You are exactly one application of L'Hospital away from getting the answer, because the next denominator will be (non-vanishing!) $\cos x$. Alternatively, we can see that three applications of L'Hospital's rule are necessary because $x - \sin x$ vanishes to third order at $0$.

---

Here's an approach using series with a detailed tracking of the error terms. We only need to keep terms up to the cubics, so we have 
$$\frac{1 + x + x^2 / 2 + x^3/6 + O(x^4) - \big(1 + \sin x + \sin^2 x / 2 + \sin^3 x / 6 + O(\sin^4 x)\big)}{x - \big(x - x^3/6 + O(x^5)\big)}$$

which is equal to

$$\frac{x + x^2/2 + x^3 / 6 + O(x^4) - (x - x^3/6 + O(x^5) + \frac 1 2(x^2 + O(x^4)) +  x^3/6 + O(x^4)}{x^3 / 6 + O(x^5)}$$

which in turn simplifies as

$$\frac{x^3 / 6 + O(x^4)}{x^3/6 + O(x^5)} \to 1.$$

Comment: You're right about being one L' Hospital away from the answer. But, I don't know taylor series yet. Also, by plugging into the $x$, 0 I got: $$e^0-(e^{\sin 0}*\cos^20-(\sin0*e^{\sin0}))-(\sin0*e^{\sin0}+\cos0*e^{\sin0})=$$
$$1-(1*1-(0*1))-1(1*1+1*1)=1-1-2=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

I propose a variant not using Taylor expansion.

Let set $u=x-\sin(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$

We have $$\dfrac{e^x-e^{\sin(x)}}{x-\sin(x)}=\dfrac{e^x-e^{x-u}}u=e^x\left(\dfrac{1-e^{-u}}u\right)$$

- the first term $e^x\to 1$
- the second term has limit $-f'(0)=1$ where $f(u)=e^{-u}$

So the overall limit is $1$.

Comment: Good solution, but it is no different from the answer posted several minutes earlier by @gimusi ... You likely were typing you answer while that solution was posted and were unaware until thereafter.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, sometimes trying to explain with more words makes your post arriving behind people's oneliners rushing for credit, but it does not matter, I'm satisfied like this.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator is approximately $e^x\,(1-e^{-x^3/6})\approx\frac{x^3}{6}e^x\approx\frac{x^3}{6}$ for small $x$. This approximation works for the denominator too, giving a limit of $1$. The cubic-over-cubic lowest-order expression also explains why using L'Hopital requires three iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the third-order Maclaurin formulae
$$
e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3),
$$
$$
\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3),
$$
$$
e^{\sin x} = e^{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)} = 
1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)^2+
\frac16 \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)^3 + o\left(\left( x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3) \right)^3 \right)= 
$$
$$
1+x-\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3);
$$
when expanding, we took into account only the summands up to the 3rd order, everything else gone into $o(x^3)$. Hence
$$
\frac{e^{\sin x}-e^x}{x-\sin x} = \frac{\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)} = \frac{\frac16+o(1)}{\frac16+o(1)} \rightarrow 1.
$$

Comment: In the last step it should be $$\frac{e^x-e^{\sin x}}{x-\sin x} = \frac{\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)} = \frac{\frac16+o(1)}{\frac16+o(1)} \rightarrow 1$$ You don't deserve a downvote in my opinion even if Taylor's expansion is not necessary for the limit, you have properly derived the expansion.

Comment: Thank you, the minuses were clearly redundant. Edited.